# Trigger code not working Uncaught error on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'm trying to trigger the first anchor of the ul but somehow my jQuery gives off this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`. I have no idea why it is doing this would appreciate any help this is my code.

```
<span style="cursor:pointer;color:#363636;" onclick="popall()">Click to zoom</span>
```

Above is event handler below is my js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
function popall(){
j('#lightgallery a:first').trigger();
}
```

I'm trying to target this.

```
<ul id="lightbox"><li><a . . . . . . .  </ul>
```

my jquery is 1.8.2 min

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the event name to be triggered to [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) like click

```
j('#lightgallery a:first').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define the which event can be handled

```
j('#lightgallery a:first').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters ] )

eventType
Type: String
A string containing a JavaScript event type, such as click or submit.

extraParameters
Type: Array or PlainObject
Additional parameters to pass along to the event handler.
```

eventType is missing